How to set parent (keep transform) in Relations on the Object panel?
I have an empty at the centre of all of these and I want to parent one of the smaller objects on the outside to it. I cannot click on the empty due to the number of overlapping objects on top of/behind/all around it.

So I tried to set parent from the Object panel under Relations

The problem is that it does not keep transform. It pops out of place and changes rotation as well. I then tried applying all transforms first then set parent in Relations, but it still pops out of place the same way.


"I cannot click on the empty due to the number of overlapping objects on top of/behind/all around it." - Have you tries Alt+Click?

hi @Leander, thank you so much for the tip! It works well.

You could also click on the empty in the Outliner to select it.

@JohnEason but I need to click the child object first, then click the empty while holding shift, which selects every object in between them in the outliner

Use Ctrl instead of Shift to click your second object/Empty?

@JohnEason oh it works, thanks!

That's how Ctrl and Shift work in Windows and I assume is standard usage!
